# native heap and ddms

Tags: android, memory, heap-memory, ddms

I manage to active the native heap tab in ddms, but columns were not updated. So  I set `libc.debug.malloc` to 1 and try to restart the emulator (2.2), but the reboot failded.
Any suggestion in order to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems that put a file in /data called local.prop with libc.debug.malloc = 1 (close and start the emulator), is the solution.